# How to create a human migration map with QGIS

Tags: qgis

I want to create a Human migration map looks like this http://postimg.org/image/an217oxh9/ or http://postimg.org/image/6ryn54ebh/ using QGIS, but don't know how to that because arrows available in QGIS are straight arrows while I need curved arrows. What plugin should I use to have such curved arrows.

Answer (score 2):

You can approximate curves with polyline features and just use qgis symbology for the arrow at the end.